# IIS self-signed aliased localhost cert rejected by browser

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate, self-signed

My self-signed localhost cert (aliased to `nate-pc-ultimate.com`) is being rejected by the browser:

[image]

You can see that I created the self-signed cert and placed it in `Certificates -> Trusted Root Certification Authorities`:

[image]

[image]

I created the cert for `nate-pc-ultimate.com` and not `localhost` because I am making API calls against a system that requires `iframe` interactions and it disallows `localhost` as the host.

I added `nate-pc-ultimate.com` to my `hosts` file as you can see:

[image]

When I view the "bad" certificate in Chrome I see this:

[image]

[image]

It appears that Chrome is not fooled by my `hosts` file entry nor the cert created for `nate-pc-ultimate.com`. It seems to blindly see `localhost` and has no awareness of `nate-pc-ultimate.com`.

I do also have a self-signed certificate made for `localhost`, which I have had for a long time. Could there be a collision going on?

What am I doing wrong? How can I solve this?

Comment: Not an answer but why do you need HTTPS for localhost development?

Comment: I forgot to mention that HTTPS is required by Authorize.net, which is the remote API system. Their js scripts that run locally detect the protocol and won't work with http alone.

Comment: Try removing the self-signed certificate made for localhost to see if that fixes it

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The cert was trying to be invoked within an IIS Express context while running a .NET MVC project within visual studio. Somehow that was causing the cert to mis-identify itself. When I published the project and ran it under true IIS, and set the IIS bindings to look at my new cert, everything worked.